# Insert the data from the data select in other table in PDO and MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-insert

There are two table

```
user:
id
uid

board:
id
message
user_id
```

The problem is , I got the uid now , and I would like to insert data to board, but I want to simplify all things to one query, so I tried

```
"INSERT INTO board (message,user_id) VALUES (:message, SELECT id FROM users WHERE uid=:uid)";
```

but in this way is not working, would anyone kindly teach me the right syntax? Thanks

Comment: Not 100% sure but try enclosing `SELECT` in parentheses like this `"INSERT INTO board (message,user_id) VALUES (:message, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE uid=:uid))";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose `SELECT` in parentheses like this

```
"INSERT INTO board (message,user_id) VALUES (:message, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE uid=:uid))";
```

Answer (score 0):

You either use a VALUES clause or a SELECT clause, not both.

```
INSERT INTO board (message, user_id)
SELECT :message, id
FROM users
WHERE uid = :uid
```